# Remote Objects duplicated on creation

Tags: remote-objects

I'm having issues with the creation of new records using remote objects: when I use the remote object `create` function instead of having only one record created I'm having two records, so the record is being duplicated.
Is anyone else having this problem? Does anyone know a solution for it?

This is what I'm using:

```
newSession.create(newSessionJson,
   function(err, sessionRecordId) { 
        if (err) { 
            alert(err); 
        } else {
            do other stuff
        }
   })
```

And this is the Json I'm using: `{Case__c: "a0KJ00000041Y4xMAE", Contact__c: "003J000001FHl9KIAT", Notes__c: "", Session_Date__c: Thu Dec 31 2015 00:00:00 GMT-0300 (BRT), Service__c: "a0RJ000000BZdW5MAL"}`

Comment: How are you triggering the remote object creation (i.e. what causes the code above to be called)? Are you getting two callbacks as well? Do you have any triggers on the object you are creating?

Comment: As @AlexTennant said, you're likely calling that piece of JS twice. Can you share some more of your code and maybe we can help you find why?